# UnitTesting a module that uses global.XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, mithril.js

Hi I'm trying to test a `mithriljs` module I developed. However the mithril source code uses `global.XMLHttpRequest` for its native request functionality.

I tried to assign an [XmlHttpRequest mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) to `global.XMLHttpRequest`, but my test is still complaining that:

> TypeError: global.XMLHttpRequest is not a function at createXhr (/path_tomodule/node_modules/mithril/mithril.js:2002:13)

[Here](https://gist.github.com/git-toni/f1b420c147eade9258de) is my test code using `tape`.

```
.js
;(function(){
  var test = require('tape');
  //global.XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
  global.XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
  var m = require('mithril');
  var Module = require('../module.js');
  var config={
    url:'/urltoken',
    title:'Hello there'
  }
  var modu=m.component(Module,{resource:config});
  test('constructor ',function(t){
    t.equal(modu.controller().url,config.url);  
    t.end();
  });
})();
```

I guess it has to do with `mithril` npm module not accessing the same scope for `global`.

Any sugestions as to how to test this module?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution, thanks to the suggestions received at mithril's [gitter room](https://gitter.im/lhorie/mithril.js?source=explore), the solution was to use `m.deps(mockedWindow)`, as explained [here](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.deps.html). The mocked window can be found in this [example](https://github.com/lhorie/mithril.js/blob/next/test-deps/mock.js) from the mithriljs sources.

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/git-toni/a3e2658fb97fd8b02121) contains the final code necessary to test the module using `tape`.

This is the `module.js` code:

```
'use strict';
var m = require('mithril');
var Module={};

Module.controller = function(args){
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.url = args.resource.url;
  ctrl.title = args.resource.title;
}

module.exports = Module;
```

The `mytest.js` test file:

```
;(function(){
  var mock = require('./mock.js');
  var m = require('mithril');
  var test = require('tape');
  var Module = require('../module.js');

  m.deps(mock.window);
  var config={
    url:'/urltoken',
    title:'Module title'
  }

  var modu=m.component(Module,{resource:config});
  test('constructor ',function(t){
    t.equal(modu.controller().url,config.url);  
    t.end();
  });
})();
```

This is the start of the mocked **window**:

```
mock = (function () {
    "use strict"

    var window = {}

    window.window = window

    var document = window.document = {
        // FIXME: add document.createRange().createContextualFragment()
    ...
```